# Javascript validation didn't work out correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple HTML form and then Use Javascript to validate form data but when I submit the form it highlight unfilled ,incorrect texboxes with red color and suddenly page direct to a form action path.what's the reason for that  Can anyone please explain I'm new to JavaScript . If want I can post my code here ..please help me.

Comment: Yes, please post your code.

Comment: You need to post some code. Your post is like calling the doctor saying "My child is crying, what is wrong with him?", how could he know? You need to bring the child to the doctor. In this case, bring your code to the community.

Comment: This is my javascript code
................

Comment: Most likely culprit is you're expecting `return false;` to do the job. You need to call `event.preventDefault();` (and set `event.returnValue` to `false` if you want to support older IE browsers).

Comment: @Erandi add your code to the question body.

Comment: @ Kasun It says code is too long to put  :(  sorry I'm new to here is there any method to put my whole code

Comment: @ null, Jonas,Dissident,Kasun,Niet ..thanks all I removed some unwanted part in my code and it yeah it worked  ..Thanks friends  :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to cancel the default event (which is to submit the form).

But that aside, *you should not use JS for form validation*. HTML5 gives us all the tools we need.

Example:

```
<input type="email" required />
```

Try typing something that's not an email address. Or nothing at all. Your browser handles it for you *in a native manner*. After all, how would a screen reader know that the text box border changing to red means it was filled in wrong?

```
<input type="date" />
```

Calendar! Hopefully... Okay, so not everything is supported yet, but the point still stands. If you write your own JS validation, you will inevitably get something wrong and spend a lot of time debugging something that the browser can already do for you ;)

Comment: @ Niet  Thanks it was worked fine when I created first time unfortunately my code is too long to put it here I did some changes in my HTML code  and I wrote javascript code to validate basic form details yeah I used HTML5 options.What I wanted was if user enter wrong data the border colour of the textbox become red and an popup alert appear saying the errors. Here when I submit it appears incorrect filed in red colour and then page refresh and redirect to the form action path. ..is there any method to put my whole code here ...